# AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'format'

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

Want to connect mysql to spark. It's showing this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):     File
>   "/home/ewebcore/Desktop/spark_prgm/spark_sql_connect.py", line 10, in
>   
>       df = SQLContext.read.format("jdbc").options( AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'format'

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext    
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession   
from pyspark.sql.types import *   
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf, StorageLevel   

df = SQLContext.read.format("jdbc").options(   
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Demo",   
driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",   
dbtable = "Bank",   
user="root",   
password="*******").load()`
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Is this your own code or are you using some tutorial? I think mine is just inaccurate.

Comment: show me ur code...